# Setting Value Linked List Nodes Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I was looking over how to remove duplicates from an unsorted Linked List and am getting confused about references in Java:

```
public static void deleteDups (LinkedListNode n){
  Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
  LinkedListNode previous = null;
  while(n!=null){
      if(table.containsKey(n.data)){
          previous.next = n.next;
      } else {
          table.put(n.data, true);
          previous = n;
      }
      n = n.next;
  }
}
```

When we do `n = n.next`, why doesn't the value of `previous` also get modified, since `previous` points to `n`?

Comment: Why don't you try using a Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `n` doesn't actually hold an instance of `LinkedListNode`.

The variable `n` holds a number. For example, it might hold the number `0x04AF34ED`.

This number is an *address*. If the processor looks for that address in the computer's RAM, it will find the data associated with a `LinkedListNode`.

The variable `previous` also holds a number. At line 10 of your source code, it happens to hold the same number as the variable `n`, which means that they point to the same object. On line 11 of your source, the variable `n` is given a new number - the address of the object `n.next`. The number assigned to `previous` doesn't change. It still holds the address of the old `LinkedListNode`.

In Java, every time you create a new object, like `List list = new ArrayList()` you're actually creating a reference to that object:

- You ask the operating system for space to store the object.
- The operating system finds a place for the object and gives you a number - the address of the memory.
- That number is assigned to the variable.
- You can access the data stored at the address given to the variable by reading fields of the object.